# Write the shortest self-identifying program (a quine variant)

Tags: code-golf, quine, decision-problem

Write a program that will generate a "true" output [iff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) the input matches the source code of the program, and which generates a "false" output iff the input does not match the source code of the program.

This problem can be described as being related to quines, as the program must be able to somehow compute its own source code in the process.

This is code golf: standard rules apply.  Your program must not access any special files, such as the file of its own source code.

*Edit: If you so choose, true/false can be replaced with True/False or 1/0.*

## Example

If the source code of your program is `bhiofvewoibh46948732));:/)4`, then here is what your program must do:

### Input (Stdin)

```
bhiofvewoibh46948732));:/)4
```

### Output (Stdout)

```
true
```

### Input

```
(Anything other than your source code)
```

### Output

```
false
```

Comment: Is the `true`/`false` output a strong requirement, or are variations (`True`/`False`, `1`/`0`) acceptable as well?

Comment: Is it a problem if the program outputs a little more than true/false (if it keeps being unambiguous and ends with true/false) ?

Comment: Related: [Interpret your lang, but not yourself?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4097/interpret-your-lang-but-not-yourself)

Comment: So you mean a Narcissist program?

Comment: [Very much related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28821/regex-that-only-matches-itself)

Answer (score 37):

## JavaScript : 26

```
function f(s){return s==f}
```

I don't know if a JavaScript file really qualifies as a "program".

Comment: +1 This works because [all objects have a `.toString()` method in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

Comment: This can be shortened using an arrow function `f=s=>s=='f='+f`

Comment: @Jonathan yes. But in 2013 it couldn't...

Answer (score 10):

## Haskell, 72 characters

```
main=interact$show.(==s++show s);s="main=interact$show.(==s++show s);s="
```

Note: there is no end-of-line character at the end of the script.

```
$ runhaskell Self.hs < Self.hs
True
```

Answer (score 9):

## Perl, <s>Infinity</s> <s>41</s> 38 Characters

```
$_=q(print<>eq"\$_=q($_);eval"|0);eval
```

**Update:** The program no longer ends with a newline, which means it will work correctly on multi-line files.  You have to enter input from STDIN without hitting enter. On Windows I was only able to do this by reading from a file.

Original solution:

```
print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(print<>==q(...
```

Comment: Nicely done! . . .

Comment: Fails for a file that begins with the code, e.g. `(cat id.pl; echo foo)|perl id.pl`

Comment: @GeoffReedy, thanks; the program did not handle multi-line input before.  It is corrected now.

Comment: Darn, is this code bowling?

Answer (score 9):

### GolfScript, 11 chars

```
{`".~"+=}.~
```

Without the `=`, this code would be a quine that generates its own source code as a string.  The `=` makes it compare this string to its input and output `1` if they match and `0` if they don't.
Note that the comparison is exact — in particular, a trailing newline at the end of the input will cause it to fail.

**Explanation:**

- `{ }` is a code block literal in GolfScript;
- `.` duplicates this code block, and `~` executes the second copy (leaving the first on the stack);
- `` ` `` stringifies the code block, and `".~"+` appends `.~` to it;
- finally, `=` compares the resulting string with the input (which is pushed on the stack as a string by the GolfScript interpreter before the program starts) and returns `1` if they match and `0` if they don't.

Answer (score 9):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 68 bytes

Fishes love eating fish poop. Now we know they can distinguish theirs from their friends'.

```
00v      0+1~$^?)0~\;n0\
  >:@@:@gi:0(?\:a=?/=?!/$1+
  0n;n*=f$=2~~/
```

You can [try it online](https://fishlanguage.com/playground) !

Comment: This outputs `1` for any prefix of the code as well

Comment: @JoKing it was worst than just prefixes of the script, it accepted truncated lines too ! I've fixed it, but I'm disappointed it's not as generic as I wanted it to be, I had to check the reached cell at the end of the script to make sure the whole code was matched. It can certainly be improved, but I'm not sure I will bother.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, 55

```
a='a=%r;print a%%a==raw_input()';print a%a==raw_input()
```

Tested:

`a='a=%r;print a%%a==raw_input()';print a%a==raw_input()` -> `True`

`(anything else)` -> `False`

Comment: Fails on any file that begins with the first line equal to `a='a=%r;print a%%a==raw_input()';print a%a==raw_input()`.

Comment: True, multi-line input is not supported.

Comment: A trivial fix would be to replace `raw_input()` with `__import__('sys').stdin.read()`.

Comment: I am confused by the challenge wording ('cause I am not good with english grammar). Is this allowed? `print raw_input()==open(__file__).read()` ? It is only 40 bytes, uses your `raw_input()` approach, but reads it's code.

Comment: @Simon That is not allowed, it is one of the standard loopholes for challenges like this.  And yes, this is what it means by `Your program must not access any special files, such as the file of its own source code.`

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
$=_=>_==`$=`+$
```

Minus two bytes thanks to Neil.

31 bytes if we must take input via prompt.

```
$=_=>prompt()==`$=${$};$()`;$()
```

38 bytes if we must output via alert.

```
$=_=>alert(prompt()==`$=${$};$()`);$()
```

This is the *proper* way to do it, as Optimizer's answer does not accept the entire source code.

Comment: Nice, although I would just write `'$='+$`.

Comment: Oh, true. @Neil

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the ending `;$()` because the function call is part of the quine. This also means that you'll need to switch to `prompt` to account for input.

Comment: @MamaFunRoll I don't think so. The OP allowed functions in other submissions.

Comment: That's not the problem. The function call is necessary _because_ it's a part of the quine. Allowing the user to call it as a function would ruin the quine.

Comment: @MamaFunRoll Then how might I incorporate input?

Comment: try `$=_=>prompt()==\`$=${$};$()\`;$()`

Answer (score 6):

## Node.js : 54

```
function f(){console.log(f+'f()'==process.argv[2])}f()
```

You test it by saving it into a file `f.js` (the exact name has no importance) and using

```
node f.js "test"
```

(which outputs false) or

```
node f.js "$(< f.js)"
```

(which outputs true)

I also made a different version based on eval :

```
eval(f="console.log('eval(f='+JSON.stringify(f)+')'==process.argv[2])")
```

It's now at 72 chars, I'll try to shorten that when I have time.

Comment: @dan1111 Why ? It doesn't access any file. I was just pointing how to launch the program to people not used to node.js. It doesn't read the file.

Comment: All of the Javascript solutions take advantage of the fact that you can access your own source code in JS.  That may not be technically "accessing the *file* of its own source code", but it accomplishes the exact same thing.   I suppose your answer is legal, though, as the question didn't specifically forbid this.

Comment: Well, you access the source of a function (only the body to be precise) which is part of the program. That's like using mixin() in D. But I don't think the two other JS answers, including one from me, really qualify as "programs", though.

Comment: @dystroy actually mixin in D is more like using eval than reading source

Comment: @ratchetfreak yes, you're right. But I think your program uses a kind of toString of the enum value, right ? And any code using eval/mixin is about the same trick than using the source of the function.

Comment: @dystroy eval/mixin requires more setup before you can access the source (like saving into a var and escaping), reading the source directly doesn't and can work on all programs in a modular fashion

Answer (score 5):

## Smalltalk (Pharo 2.0 dialect), 41 bytes

Implement this **41** chars method in String (ugly formatting for code-golf):

```
isItMe^self=thisContext method sourceCode
```

Then evaluate this in a Workspace (printIt the traditional Smalltalk way)
The input is not read from stdin, it's just a String to which we send the message (what else a program could be in Smalltalk?):

```
'isItMe^self=thisContext method sourceCode' isItMe.
```

But we are cheating, sourceCode reads some source file...
Here is a variant with **51** chars which does not:

```
isItMe
    ^ self = thisContext method decompileString
```

And test with:

```
'isItMe
    ^ self = thisContext method decompileString' isItMe
```

If a String in a Workspace is not considered a valid input, then let's see how to use some Dialog Box in **116** chars
Just evaluate this sentence:

```
(UIManager default request: 'type me') = (thisContext method decompileString withSeparatorsCompacted allButFirst: 7)
```

Since decompile format includes CR and TAB, we change that withSeparatorsCompacted.
Then we skip the first 7 chars are 'doIt ^ '

Finally a **105** chars variant using stdin, just interpret this sentence from command line, just to feel more mainstream:

```
Pharo -headless Pharo-2.0.image eval "FileStream stdin nextLine = (thisContext method decompileString withSeparatorsCompacted allButFirst: 7)"
```

Answer (score 4):

## flex - 312 chars

```
Q \"
N \n
S " "
B \\
P "Q{S}{B}{Q}{N}N{S}{B}n{N}S{S}{Q}{S}{Q}{N}B{S}{B}{B}{N}P{S}{Q}{P}{Q}{N}M{S}{Q}{M}{Q}{N}%%{N}{P}{N}{M}{N} putchar('1');"
M "(.|{N})* putchar('0');"
%%
Q{S}{B}{Q}{N}N{S}{B}n{N}S{S}{Q}{S}{Q}{N}B{S}{B}{B}{N}P{S}{Q}{P}{Q}{N}M{S}{Q}{M}{Q}{N}%%{N}{P}{N}{M}{N} putchar('1');
(.|{N})* putchar('0');
```

Can probably be made shorter, but it works with multi-line input (necessary since the source code is multiple lines) and even for inputs that contain the program as a substring. It seems many of the answers so far fail on one or both of these.

Compile command: `flex id.l && gcc -lfl lex.yy.c`

Answer (score 3):

### D (133 chars)

```
enum c=q{import std.stdio;import std.algorithm;void main(){auto i=readln();writeln(equal("auto c=q{"~c~"};mixin(c);",i));}};mixin(c);
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (V8), 35

```
function i(){alert(prompt()==i+[])}
```

call `i()` and it will prompt for input

Comment: The `+[]` should be optional as JS will auto-type-cast it

Answer (score 3):

## GolfScript - 26

```
":@;[34]@+2*=":@;[34]@+2*=
```

Inspired from http://esolangs.org/wiki/GolfScript#Examples

Another version:

```
"[34].@@;+2*="[34].@@;+2*=
```

Too bad that `\` is both swap and escape...

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 187 bytes

```
import sys;code="import sys;code=!X!;print(sys.stdin.read()==code.replace(chr(33),chr(34)).replace(!X!,code,1))";print(sys.stdin.read()==code.replace(chr(33),chr(34)).replace("X",code,1))
```

Careful not to add newline at the end. Someone with better Python-fu might be able to shorten it.

Comment: You can use `C=chr` to drop several bytes. Also, shorten the variable name `code`.

Comment: Since nobody said it for over a year, Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 47 bytes

```
_='_=%r;print _%%_==input()';print _%_==input()
```

A simple quine with the added check.

Comment: This doesn't work. `print` is a function is Python 3. You'd need to do `print(_%%_==input())';print(_%_==input())` or change it to Python 2.

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 12 bytes

```
{s"_~"+q=}_~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7pYKb5OSbvQtja@DpUHAA)

#### Explanation

This just uses the standard CJam quine framework.

```
{s"_~"+q=}    e# Push this block (function literal).
          _~  e# Copy and run it.
```

What the block does:

```
 s            e# Stringify the top element (this block itself).
  "_~"+       e# Append "_~". Now the source code is on the stack.
       q      e# Read the input.
        =     e# Check if it equals the source code.
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I had ._.

Answer (score 2):

### Tcl, 111 chars

```
set c {set c {$c};puts [expr {[read stdin] eq [subst -noc \$c]}]};puts [expr {[read stdin] eq [subst -noc $c]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 52 char

```
$_='$/=$\;$_="\$_=\47$_\47;eval";print<>eq$_|0';eval
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
=hS+s"=hS+s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3zYjWLtYCUz@h/JiIFwA)

#### Explanation

The explanation uses `¨` to delimit strings (to avoid unreadable escaping):

```
     "=hS+s  -- string literal: ¨=hS+s¨
  S+         -- join itself with
    s        -- | itself "showed": ¨"=hS+s"¨
             -- : ¨=hS+s"=hS+s"¨
 h           -- init: ¨=hS+s"=hS+s¨
=            -- is the input equal?
```

By removing the function `=` you can [verify](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PyNYu1jJFkT@/w8A) that it will indeed only match the source itself.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 bytes

```python
s="print's=%r;exec s'%s==input()";exec s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWqaAoM69EvdhWtcg6tSI1WaFYXbXY1jYzr6C0RENTCSr2/7@SkhKxioFKAQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 24 bytes

```
'1rd3*i={*}50l3-?.~i)*n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X92wKMVYK9O2WqvW1CDHWNdery5TUyvPGrcMAA)

Wrapping string literal followed by checking whether the input is identical to the stack, with a final check that there is no more input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
“Ṿ;$⁼”Ṿ;$⁼
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO/dZqzxq3POoYS6M@f9w@6OmNf//R6tjl1fX4VJQR4gjK0GTQtWCRymYg64ILBELAA)

```
“Ṿ;$⁼”Ṿ;$⁼
“Ṿ;$⁼”      String literal: 'Ṿ;$⁼'
        $   Next two links act on the string literal
      Ṿ     Uneval: '“Ṿ;$⁼”'
       ;    Append string: '“Ṿ;$⁼”Ṿ;$⁼' (source code)
         ⁼  Is the string above equal to the input?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 33 bytes

```sh
f () {
	[ "`type -f f`" = $1 ]
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/TUFDU6GaizNaQSmhpLIgVUE3TSEtQUnBVkHFUCGWq5YLqEJJRQMupanElZqcka@gYs/FpayQmJKiUFKUmJmTmZeuUFyQmJzKhaZcAbf6vNRyII2hgwtFR1Fqbn5ZKnZN1cjaVO1r4Rr/AwA)

The extra spaces, tab, and newlines are required. `type -f f` does not print the original source, but the function formatted in a particular way, with indentation and a trailing newline.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 54 bytes

```r
f=function(s)s==paste0("f=function(s)s==", body(f)[3])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P802rTQvuSQzP0@jWLPY1rYgsbgk1UBDCV1cSUchKT@lUiNNM9o4VvN/moY6eTrVNbmAehOTklPUNf8DAA)

`body` gets the body of the function (splitting it a bit, so that `body(f)[3]` is everything from `paste0` onwards). Interestingly, `body` reformats the code, adding spaces after commas, etc. This is thus a rare case of an R golf answer with a space after a comma.

This works because `body(f)` is an object of type `language`, and there exists an `as.character` method for this type. On the other hand, `f` and `args(f)` are of type `closure`, and cannot be converted to character type as far as I can tell. Please don't ask me what the language type is for…

Comment: As we've noted before, R's code-reformatting is quite version-dependent.  My old R version 3.2.1 let's me use ```f=function(x)x==paste0('f=',capture.output(f))``` successfully for only 46 bytes, but the later version in TIO fills it up with annoying spaces & newlines...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Good find! `capture.output` works as you would want on my later version of R (3.6.3), but it adds a bytecode at the end. The output is thus a vector of 2 logicals: the first one corresponds to what you want, the second tests equality with the bytecode. I believe this is acceptable: in R, a vector of two logicals is truthy iff the first logical is `TRUE` (per the definition along the lines of "how would `if` handle it?). You should post this separately!

Comment: Thanks very much for checking that!  It seems that only specific R versions don't work (annoyingly including the one at TIO) - I now tested version 4 and it works Ok, too.  So I've posted a separate [version-dependent R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217276/95126) answer now.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) (version-dependent), 46 bytes

```r
f=function(x)x==paste0('f=',capture.output(f))
```

`capture.output` - as the function name suggests - retrieves the text string that results from entering the function name `f` directly to [R](https://www.r-project.org/), which should output the body of the function.  We manually prepend this with `f=` so that it exactly* matches the program code, and check whether the function argument `x` is the same as this.
*See below

There are a couple of caveats, though, that depend on the [R](https://www.r-project.org/) version used:

1. Early versions of [R](https://www.r-project.org/) (like my own version 3.2.1) return the originally-defined function body as-is when the function name is entered to [R](https://www.r-project.org/).  However, later versions add additional formatting, like inserting spaces and newlines, which breaks this code: this unfortunately includes the installation (3.5.2) on 'Try it online'.  Later still, much newer [R](https://www.r-project.org/) versions (I tested 4.0.3) return to the as-is output formatting and everything is Ok again...  except...
2. The most recent versions of [R](https://www.r-project.org/) compile functions at the first run, and thereafter append a 'byte code' specific for the compiled function to the outputted function body.  This means that `capture.output` returns two strings, beginning at the second time the function is run.  Luckily, the function body is still the first one (the byte code is the second one), so the result of supplying the program code as input is `TRUE FALSE`, which evaluates to 'truthy' in [R](https://www.r-project.org/) and so counts as a 'true' output for this challenge.

Special thanks to [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86301/robin-ryder) for helping to uncover the version-dependence of [R](https://www.r-project.org/)'s function outputting.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 12 bytes

```
`:q$+=`:q$+=
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%3Aq%24%2B%3D%60%3Aq%24%2B%3D&inputs=%60%3Aq%24%2B%3D%60%3Aq%24%2B%3D&header=&footer=)

I finished making this, and then realized that it is almost identical to the Vyxal quine that @Lyxal wrote, but with the addition of `=` to check if the input is equal.

Explanation:

```
              # Implicit input
`:q$+=`       # Push the string ':q$+='
       :      # Duplicate the string
        q     # Quotify; put backticks around the topmost string
         $    # Swap the top two values on the stack
          +   # Concatenate the two strings
           =  # Check if the input is equal to the string
              # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

### C - <strike>186</strike> 176 characters

One liner:

```
 *a="*a=%c%s%c,b[999],c[999];main(){sprintf(b,a,34,a,34);gets(c);putchar(strcmp(b,c)?'0':'1');}",b[999],c[999];main(){sprintf(b,a,34,a,34);gets(c);putchar(strcmp(b,c)?'0':'1');}
```

With whitespace (note that this breaks the program):

```
*a="*a=%c%s%c,b[999],c[999];main(){sprintf(b,a,34,a,34);gets(c);putchar(strcmp(b,c)?'0':'1');}",b[999],c[999];
main() {
  sprintf(b,a,34,a,34);
  gets(c);
  putchar(strcmp(b,c)?'0':'1');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#PowerShell, 28 bytes

Very similar to [this JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11376/48455), uses [function provider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_function_provider).

```powershell
filter f{"$Function:f"-eq$_}
```

#Example

```powershell
PS > '"$Function:f"-eq$_' | f
True

PS > 'xxx' | f
False
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 26 bytes

```
"34bLN26)s:f="34bLN26)s:f=
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%2234bLN26%29s%3Af%3D%2234bLN26%29s%3Af%3D&i=%2234bLN26%29s%3Af%3D%2234bLN26%29s%3Af%3D%0A%2234bLN26%29s%3Af%3D%2234bLN26%29s%3Afb%0Aabc%0A34&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript ES6, 14 bytes

Like the other javascript answer but includes it's entire source code and not just the function

```
a=q=>'a='+a==q
```

Example usage:

```
a("q=>'a='+a==q") // returns false
a("a=q=>'a='+a==q") // returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0"D34çýQ"D34çýQ
```

Modifies the default [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) [`0"D34çý"D34çý`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97899/52210) by adding `Q` (check for equality with the implicit input)

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQMnF2OTw8sN7A@EMrIIA)

**Explanation:**

```python
0                # Push 0 to the stack
                 #  STACK: [0]
 "D34çýQ"        # Push the string 'D34çýQ' to the stack
                 #  STACK: [0, 'D34çýIå']
         D       # Duplicate this string
                 #  STACK: [0, 'D34çýIå', 'D34çýIå']
          34ç    # Push '"' to the stack
                 #  STACK: [0, 'D34çýIå', 'D34çýIå', '"']
             ý   # Join the stack by this '"' delimiter
                 #  STACK: ['0"D34çýIå"D34çýIå']
              Q  # Check if it's equal to the (implicit) input
                 # (and output the top of the stack implicitly as result)
```

---

Cool **15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** alternative provided by *@Grimy*:

```
187745012D27BJQ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0MLc3MTUwNDIxcjcySsQQwAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
187745012        # Push integer 187745012 
                 #  STACK: [187745012]
         D       # Duplicate it
                 #  STACK: [187745012, 187745012]
          27     # Push integer 27
                 #  STACK: [187745012, 187745012, 27]
            B    # Convert 187745012 to base-27
                 #  STACK: [187745012, "D27BJQ"]
             J   # Join the values on the stack together
                 #  STACK: ["187745012D27BJQ"]
              Q  # Check if it's equal to the (implicit) input
                 # (and output the top of the stack implicitly as result)
```

Comment: `187745012D27BJQ` is a tie.

Answer (score 1):

## q, 8 bytes

```
{x~.z.s}
```

Return boolean on input matching the self-referential [.z.s](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zs-self)

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 11 bytes

```
"3X4+kSqi=@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/1/JOMJEOzu4MNPWAYXDBQA)

TIO got updated and there's no longer an issue reading input (and no longer requires a trailing whitespace).

#### Explanation

```
>                 Implicit entry
 "                Begin reading as string
  3X4+kSqi=@      Pushed to the stack as a string, loop around
 "                End reading as string
  3X4+            Push 3*10 and 4 to the stack, add them together
      k           Convert to character (")
       S          Swap the top two items on the stack
        q         Concatenate. This leaves only "3X4+kSqi=@ on the stack
         i        Read input
          =       Compare using .Equals, push 1 if equal, else 0
           @      Print and terminate
```

### JoKing's solution:

```
"'<~qi=@|
```

#### Explanation

```
  <              Entry
 '               Read character (loop around)
"                Push "
         |       Mirror
"                Begin reading string (loop around)
 '<~ri=@|        Push the string '<~qi=@| (loop around)
"                End reading string
 '<~             Push the character < and then discard it
    q            Concatenate, stack contains only "'<~qi=@|
      i          Read input
       =         Compare
        @        Print and terminate
```

Comment: [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/1/dpq6oMNPWoUYJmc0FAA)

Comment: @JoKing Very clever.

Comment: Actually, [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/19J3aauMNPWoQaJyQUA "Runic Enchantments – Try It Online") avoids the `r`everse

Comment: @JoKing I probably should've been able to arrive at that (from the 10 byte solution) myself, but I haven't had my [cawfee](https://cawcawfee.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/caw-cawfeee.jpg?w=300) yet. I'd already worked out yesterday that having the `"` on the left is the only place it can really go, because having it elsewhere complicates things. (But just now I had to run it in my debugger to see what it was doing...)

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>36</s> <s>28</s> 26 bytes

```
`:&\`ⁿ^\`ⁿ&⅀=`:&\`ⁿ^\`ⁿ&⅀=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/wUotJuFR4/44MKn2qLXBFosQseoA)

Same concept as before, but shorter.

### Answer History

```
`:&\`ⁿ⅍^\`ⁿ⅍++&+¿=`:&\`ⁿ⅍^\`ⁿ⅍++&+¿=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/wUotJuFR4/5Hrb1xMIa2tpr2of22eKTI1QcA)

Who knew generating a program that knows itself would be so unreadable!

### Explained

The very first step here is to generate the string that will be checked against. At this point, we don't particularly know what the checking part will look like, but we do know that there will be a string that looks like so:

```
`\`ⁿ⅍^\`ⁿ⅍++`
```

Which would consequently be followed by:

```
 \`ⁿ⅍^\`ⁿ⅍++
```

This creates a string which contains itself quoted... Something needed for when input is taken, as the quotes are going to be present.

From here, string equality is quite easy, coming in at a trivial 2 bytes:

```
¿=
```

Incorporating this into the string gives:

```
`\`ⁿ⅍^\`ⁿ⅍++¿=`\`ⁿ⅍^\`ⁿ⅍++¿=
```

At this stage, one might think the quine is complete... It has the string part and it has the equality part... What else could be needed? Well. Let me tell you we ain't done yet.

Y'see, we have a quoted string on the stack, but we don't have it's unquoted equivalent present, meaning we need to account for that. The register works well here:

```
`:&\`ⁿ⅍^\`ⁿ⅍++&+¿=`:&\`ⁿ⅍^\`ⁿ⅍++&+¿=
```

And there you have it: a self identifying program written completely on a phone keyboard.

Comment: It still outputs `1` if the input is followed by a newline and then anything else

Comment: Well of course it would, because Keg only reads one line at a time. I'll have to clarify input methods with Keg, because otherwise multi line input isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 33 bytes

```perl6
<dd "<$_>~~.EVAL"eq slurp>~~.EVAL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/98mJUVByUYl3q6uTs81zNFHKbVQoTintKgAJkCEEgA)

Outputs either `Bool::True` or `Bool::False` to STDERR. This is the basic quine format, with an added check against input (`eq slurp`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <sup><s>22</s> <s>16</s></sup> 14 bytes

```
"iQ ²¶U"iQ ²¶U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/XykzUOHQpkPbQuGM///VMQXVAQ)

### Explanation

```
"iQ ²¶U"iQ ²¶U
"iQ ²¶U"        // Take this string.        iQ ²¶U
        iQ      // Insert a quote.          "iQ ²¶U
           ²    // Double.                  "iQ ²¶U"iQ ²¶U
            ¶U  // Check if equal to input.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-0n`, <sup><s>32</s></sup> 27 bytes

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to a comment by @Sisyphus on another answer.*

```ruby
eval s="p$_=='eval s=%p'%s"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P7UsMUeh2FapQCXe1lYdylMtUFctVsIr@S@/oCQzP6/4v65BHgA)

Disclosure: very similar to my [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213644/92901) on a duplicate question.

The `-0` flag sets the null byte as the input record separator. Without `-0`, each line of the input would be read (and tested for equality with the code) separately.

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc), 132 bytes

```c
#define Q(X)main(c,v)int**v;{return!strcmp(#X"\nQ("#X")",v[1]);}
Q(#define Q(X)main(c,v)int**v;{return!strcmp(#X"\nQ("#X")",v[1]);})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIVAjQjM3MTNPI1mnTDMzr0RLq8y6uii1pLQoT7G4pCg5t0BDOUIpJi9QQwlIayrplEUbxmpa13IFalBqhOb/weEMAA)

It turns out using a macro works out better than using `(a)sprintf`, even with `%c%s%1$c`.

I'm not sure if this type of input (a single multiline command-line argument) and output (return value of 1 for true or 0 for false) are allowed.

If they aren't:

---

## C (gcc), 152 bytes

```c
x,y[99];main(z){asprintf(&x,z="x,y[99];main(z){asprintf(&x,z=%c%s%1$c,34,z);gets(y);putchar(48+!strcmp(x,y));}",34,z);gets(y);putchar(48+!strcmp(x,y));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/79CpzLa0jLWOjcxM0@jSrM6sbigKDOvJE1DrUKnylYJv7RqsmqxqqFKso6xiU6VpnV6akmxRqWmdUFpSXJGYpGGiYW2YnFJUXJugQbQHE1N61ololUOXpcBAA)

Assumes an ASCII environment. Reads from stdin, writes 1 or 0 to stdout. Abuses ints as pointers, leaks memory, and uses the dreaded `gets` :)

---

In case you're curious, here's the opposite combinations of quine and IO methods:

#### C (gcc), 136 bytes

```c
x;main(y,v)int**v;{asprintf(&x,y="x;main(y,v)int**v;{asprintf(&x,y=%c%s%1$c,34,y);return!strcmp(x,v[1]);}",34,y);return!strcmp(x,v[1]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/COjcxM0@jUqdMMzOvREurzLo6sbigCMhO01Cr0Km0VSKoQjVZtVjVUCVZx9hEp1LTuii1pLQoT7G4pCg5t0CjQqcs2jBW07pWCb/0/8HjFAA)

#### C (gcc), 158 bytes

```c
#define Q(X)v[40];main(){read(0,v,159);putchar(48+!strcmp(#X"\nQ("#X")",v));}
Q(#define Q(X)v[40];main(){read(0,v,159);putchar(48+!strcmp(#X"\nQ("#X")",v));})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIVAjQrMs2sQg1jo3MTNPQ7O6KDUxRcNAp0zH0NRS07qgtCQ5I7FIw8RCW7G4pCg5t0BDOUIpJi9QQwlIayrplGlqWtdyBWpQ1TzNwe4@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 48 bytes

```julia
(a=:(show(ARGS[] == "(a=:($(a)))|>eval")))|>eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XyPR1kqjOCO/XMMxyD04OlbB1lZBCSyoopGoqalZY5dalpijBGf9J10LAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 38 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.75 bytes

```
`I=`I=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiYEk9YEk9IiwiIiwiSceOYyJd)

### Explained

```
`I=`I=­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
     =  # ‎⁡Does the input equal
`I=`    # ‎⁢The string "I="
    I   # ‎⁣With itself wrapped in backticks prepended
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 1):

## Uiua, 38 bytes

```
≅&sc⊂∶!(⊂⊂↷.+1@!)."≅&sc⊂:!(⊂⊂↷.+1@!)."
```

### Explained

```
≅&sc⊂∶!(⊂⊂↷.+1@!)."≅&sc⊂:!(⊂⊂↷.+1@!)."­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
                  "≅&sc⊂:!(⊂⊂↷.+1@!)."  # ‎⁡The string "≅&sc⊂:!(⊂⊂↷.+1@!)."
                 .                      # ‎⁢Duplicate it
      !(        )                       # ‎⁣Call the following function on the top copy:
           .+1@!                        # ‎⁤  Push two "
         ⊂↷                             # ‎⁢⁡  Append the first
        ⊂                               # ‎⁢⁢  Prepend the second
# ‎⁢⁣The top of the stack is now a quotified string
    ⊂∶                                  # ‎⁢⁤Prepend the original string without quotes
≅&sc                                    # ‎⁣⁡Does that equal the input?
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 19 bytes

```
ñOÑ~"qpxØ¥^¨©î±¥$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///BG/8MTpeuUCgsqDs84tDTu0IpDjYdWHl53aOOhpSoEpAE)

Prints **1** or **0**. Here is a hexdump:

```
00000000: f14f d11b 7e22 7170 78d8 a55e a881 a9ee  .O..~"qpx..^....
00000010: b1a5 24                                  ..$
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 288 bytes (Full Program with STDIN)

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){String s="interface M{static void main(String[]a){String s=%c%s%1$c;System.out.print(s.format(s,34,s).equals(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine()));}}";System.out.print(s.format(s,34,s).equals(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine()));}}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##7ZCxCsJAEER/5QgG7kAPRLvgH2iVUiyWy0Y2JnvxbhOVkG@PAe3Fws5uYHiPYSroYeVb5Kq4TBOxYCjBoToMUUDIqd5ToRog1rkE4vPxBGZ4RRV3yddE6tKYrhcuyx9RsLG@E9vOnehoSx8amMNys11GY/HaQR01401V80zbCdU2d8CMQb9xYmMZ77InRm2MycYx@Z36/9An9RM)

## Java 8, 210 bytes (Full Program with Console Arguments)

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){String s="interface M{static void main(String[]a){String s=%c%s%1$c;System.out.print(s.format(s,34,s).equals(a[0]));}}";System.out.print(s.format(s,34,s).equals(a[0]));}}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNL0jNy0rJ/v8/M68ktSgtMTlVwbe6uCSxJDNZoSw/M0UhNzEzTyO4pCgzLz06NlGzGsJUKLZVIlmHarJqsaqhSrJ1cGVxSWquXn5piV4BUK5Eo1gvLb8oNxHI0DE20SnW1EstLE3MKdZIjDaI1dS0rq1VIkPP/@HoKQA)

## Java 8, 108 bytes (Function)

```java
i->{String s="i->{String s=%c%s%1$c;return s.format(s,34,s).equals(i);}";return s.format(s,34,s).equals(i);}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##vY8xC8IwFIT3/oqHWEigBkW3Uv@BXRzF4RmjpLZJzXsVRPrba8Q6uDm5HBx3cN9VeMOZb42rjpdB10gEG7TukQBYxyacUBsoXxbg4H1t0IEWWw7WnYFkHoM@iUKMbDWU4KCAwc7Wj0@nmHy5VKeULqY6D4a74IDUyYcGWVC2XGUklbl2WJOwMu8nv5SG/LXfdoc67o8YN2@P0MQfI@luDyjfJ7Z3YtMo37FqY8TCKS1wN9/L8Uw//BX/CQ)

**Explanation:**

[quine](/questions/tagged/quine)-part:

- The `String s` contains the unformatted source code.
- `%s` is used to input this String into itself with the `s.format(...)`.
- `%c`, `%1$c` and the `34` are used to format the double-quotes.
- `s.format(s,34,s)` puts it all together

Challenge-part:

- `.equals(...)` checks if this formatted source code equals the input.

  - `java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine()` is used as this input for STDIN
  - `a[0]` is used as this input for Console arguments
  - `i` is used as this input for the lambda function

Answer (score 0):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), <s>167</s> 157 bytes

```pascal
const b=#39';var s:string;begin read(s);write(s=a+b+#39#59#97#61#39+a+b)end.';a='const b=#39';var s:string;begin read(s);write(s=a+b+#39#59#97#61#39+a+b)end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsTk7M0U0rSP7/Pzk/r7hEIclW2dhS3bossUih2Kq4pCgzL906KTU9M0@hKDUxRaNY07q8KLMkVaPYNlE7SRuoVtnUUtnSXNnMEMjWBopppual6KlbJ9qqU9PAQe48AA)

While substring can be easily extracted, like in my [regular quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173116/60517), unfortunately, they cannot be concatenated because FPC thinks it is an array in these circumstances. In `a` and `b` are characters before and after constant definitions. `#39#59#97#61#39` is a replacement for `';a='` as this is not represented in the constants. `#39` represents `'` and is at the start of `b`, glued together to the rest of `b`, to shorten the comparison expression as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

## TeX, 55 bytes

The file has to be saved as `a.tex` and should be run using `pdftex a.tex`. The script doesn't terminate after returning 1 or 0, if that should be necessary append it by `\end` (+4 bytes). If it should work for arbitrary file names replace `\openin0a` with `\openin0\jobname` (+7 bytes).

```latex
\openin0=a\read0to\0\read1to~\message{\ifx\0~1\else0\fi}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 42 bytes

```python
exec(s:="print('exec(s:=%r)'%s==input())")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7UiNVmj2MpWqaAoM69EQx3GVy3SVFcttrXNzCsoLdHQ1FTSJEUtAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 318 bytes

```
interface Q{static void main(String[]a){char q=34;String s="interface Q{static void main(String[]a){char q=34;String s=%c%s%c;System.out.print(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().equals(String.format(s,q,s,q)));}}";System.out.print(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().equals(String.format(s,q,s,q)));}}
```

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/aGyxvm)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¶BîQi"¶BîQi
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=tkLuUWkitkLuUWk&input=J7ZC7lFpIrZC7lFpJw)

```
¶BîQi"¶BîQi     :Implicit input of string
¶               :Is strictly equal to
 B              :  11
  î             :  Mold to length B
   Q            :    Quotation mark
    i           :    Prepend
     "¶BîQi     :      Literal string
```