# A regexp that does not match itself

Tags: regular-expression

Can you think of a regular expression that does not match itself?

Comment: `a{2}`, and many more

Comment: Welcome to Protramming Puzzles & Code Golf! I think this question is a bit too broad, there's very many regexpes that doesn't match them self. I would also suggest adding a objective winning criteria, such as code-golf (shortest regexp wins) or popularity contest (answer with the most votes wins).

Comment: `^$` - Can't think of shorter for now..

Comment: This should have been closed as a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22648/194

Answer (score 4):

A few on 2 chars

```
^$

\s

\d

\n

\t

\r
```

And many more consisting of a \ and a lowercase character.