# Transformers in Disguise (Cops' Thread)

Tags: code-challenge, cops-and-robbers

[The robber's thread is here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/175366/76162)

The cops task is to write a function or program that, when given an input of itself, outputs a finite deterministic string. If the program is given a different input, it should return a different output.

### Rules:

- Submissions consist of

  - Language name

    - If any flags are used, they should be revealed.
  - Byte count of program
  - Byte count of output
  - Output

    - If it is particularly long, please provide a pastebin or something similar
    - If it contains unprintables, please provide a hexdump.
    - Trailing newlines and whitespace should be included in the output
  - Where the input is coming from (STDIN, command line, [etc.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/76162))
- If applicable, you may assume that the byte representing EOF is not present in the input, unless you use that byte in your program.
- If your program is cracked, add a link to the corresponding answer in the robber's thread in your title.
- Your program is not safe until a week has passed and you mark it so.
- I disapprove of techniques like seeding random with the input or cryptographic hash functions. I can't stop them, but **I will not be accepting a solution that utilises either of these**. Also note that some of these techniques might have collisions, where a different string produces the same output.
- Your goal is to have the shortest output. The shortest safe solution posted within three weeks of posting this question wins!

The robber's task is to find a program of size equal to or less than the original, which also obeys the above rules.

If a robber cracks your program with a different solution than intended, then you have the opportunity to 'uncrack' it by proving that the robber's solution is incorrect. You can do this by finding an input to the robber's program that will produce the same output.

### Example Submission:

#### brainfuck, 10 bytes, Score: 10

```
]<.[<],>[,
```

This solution is [,[>,]<[.<]](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ9pOJ9YmWs8mFpkNAA) which simply reverses the input

Good luck!

Comment: "If the program is given a different input, it should return a different output." Does this means the program should never output the same thing for other inputs? Or does this means the program should not constantly output something regardless the input? (EXIST an input not equals to itself, vs., FORALL inputs not equal to itself, return a different output.)

Comment: @tsh Only the input of itself must have a unique output. For example, a valid submission could be a [self-identifying program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11370/76162), which outputs `1` for itself and `0` otherwise

Comment: @JoKing  So your example Python 3 submission is invalid? Because it obvoiusly also outputs `1021111143210532105110321051101121171164041581121141051101164011111410040105414410111010061393941` for some other strings.

Comment: @lynn You're right. I've removed that example

Answer (score 4):

## [7](http://esolangs.org/wiki/7), 31 characters, score 30, safe but possibly broken?

A 7 program is normally just a number, but it can contain whitespace, splitting it into multiple numbers. This submission therefore consists of two numbers (which are implicitly concatenated by the 7 interpreter), and the program likewise takes two numbers as input, via standard input. (The "31 characters" in the header is the total length of the two numbers, plus one separating whitespace character; the digits that make up the numbers are interpreted as octal when used as a program, but decimal when used as an input, and it's the digits that are the same in the two cases, not the actual numbers. Note that it's irrelevant either when treated as a program, or when treated as an input, whether you separate them with a space or a newline; I hope that doesn't invalidate the submission.)

The expected output is the following number (expressed here in decimal, as that's the output format that the 7 interpreter uses):

```
238363505302130098723162537059
```

Note that the 7 interpreter linked from the Esolang wiki internally stores numbers in unary, meaning you're unlikely to have enough memory to actually run the program on itself to see what it does. I verified the program via working out its behaviour manually, and testing it on small inputs to verify that it did what I expected it to do. An alternative approach would be to write an interpreter that uses a more efficient method of storing numbers.

Avoiding cracks here was something of a pain, but I'm finally now satisfied that no two numbers other than those in the program itself are capable of producing 238363505302130098723162537059 as output. (*EDIT 1 week later: I may have been wrong, depending on how you interpret the question; see below.*)

### Solution

The original program was:

> ```
> 711170237403706
> 111723603700633
> ```
>
> This program takes two numbers \$x\$ and \$y\$, and calculates the result of the expression \$3xy-y-2\$ (i.e. \$y(3x-1)-2\$). If we perform this calculation at \$x=711170237403706\$ and \$y=111723603700633\$, [we get a result of \$238363505302130098723162537059\$ as required](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v0LBVsHc0NDQ3MDI2NzEwNjcwIyrEigGEjIyNgMJGJgZG3MVFGXmlWhUamkYa1XoGmrqGmn@/w8A).

It was intended that no other input will give the desired result because:

> The input must be chosen such that \$y(3x-1)-2=238363505302130098723162537059\$, i.e. \$y(3x-1)=238363505302130098723162537061\$ (adding 2 to both sides). This number is a semiprime, with only two factors: \$111723603700633\$ and \$2133510712211117\$. Only one of these numbers, \$2133510712211117\$, can be expressed in the form \$3x-1\$ (giving \$(3 \times 711170237403706)-1=2133510712211117\$). So we can uniquely identify which number is \$x\$ and which is \$y\$, meaning that only one input works.

However, depending on how you interpret the question, there may be a second input that produces the desired output (thus invalidating this solution):

> Unfortunately, there are two multiplicative partitions of a semiprime into two factors: one is to divide it into the two prime factors, but the other is the trivial partition consisting of \$1\$ and the number itself. \$1\$ cannot be written in the form \$3x-1\$ with integer \$x\$, but the desired output can be; thus a potential meta-crack involves giving the input as \$79454501767376699574387512354\$ and \$1\$. However, the first number here involves characters (\$8\$ and \$9\$) which are not in the character set for 7 programs. So if input is restricted to being in the same character set as the program, this solution is valid; but if input containing characters from outside the program's character set is allowed, this solution is invalid.

### Explanation

Here's how the intended solution functions:

> ```
> 711170237403706 111723603700633
> 7   7   7                         Stack element separators
>  111 023 403706 111723603700633   Initial stack elements
>  111                              Number 3, in unary
>      023                          I/O DSL for "input a number"
>          403706 111723603700633   Main program
> (Implicit: execute a copy of the main program element, preserving the original)
>          40                       Swap {023} above {program}, escaping it
>            3                      Do I/O using {023}; pop {program}
>      0                            I/O: numeric
>       23                          Input a number, copying {111} that many times
>             706                   Append "6" to the number (decrementing it)
>                 11                Push two empty stack elements
>                   17236           Push a stack element "23" (unescaped)
>                        0          Escape {23}, consuming an empty element
>                         3         Do I/O using {23}; pop {the element below}
>                     23            Copy the top of stack input many times
>                          7006     Append "66" (i.e. subtract 2)
>                              3    Output {as a number}
>                               3   Exit the program (due to low stack)
> ```
>
> The leading 7 and trailing 3 aren't necessary for the program's functionality, they're just there to get the prime factors of the output right. It helps to follow this program if you understand the numeric format; numbers are stored in a unary variant in which `1` and `7` increase the value by 1, and `0` and `6` decrease the value by 1 (thus appending `66` decreases the value by 2, repeating the number multiplies it, and so on). Input's done by repeating a stack element (thus if the stack element is `12345` and the input is \$3\$, the new stack element will be \$123451234512345\$).

Answer (score 3):

## [Node.js v10.9.0](https://tio.run/#javascript-node), 40 bytes, Score: 40, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175441/58563)

#### Input

This is a function taking exactly one parameter.

#### Output

```
&`nij.9=j.,)r31n=+(=ooj`[o.o.)1.s](>=6>t
```

Comment: I can only rearrange into ```o=>[...j=o,].sort(n=>(j+=113)&69).join`` ```, but `j` can't go to integer

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175441/42545) That was quite fun :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [A Pear Tree](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A_Pear_Tree), 46 bytes of ASCII, score 0, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175965/76359)

Input is taken from standard input. The expected output (on standard output) is an empty string (i.e. when the program is given itself as argument, no output should be printed).

In other words, the challenge here is to write an A Pear Tree program that does not output anything on standard output when given itself on standard input, and which does output something on standard output when given something other than itself on standard input, using no more than 46 bytes. (I've managed to do this while holding the program to printable ASCII, too, despite A Pear Tree frequently using non-ASCII and unprintable characters.) This is effectively the task of writing a [self-identifying program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11370/write-the-shortest-self-identifying-program-a-quine-variant), with a specific output format (i.e. null string when self-identification succeeds); however, A Pear Tree has at least two twists that make the task somewhat more difficult than it looks when done in this specific language (which is why I chose it for my cop submission).

### My solution

My solution is a bit different from the crack:

```
eval(k=q(print$\=$_="eval(k=q($k))"ne$_;MZpa))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9QtSE0s0i0pSk39/z@1LDFHI9u2UKOgKDOvRCXGViXeVgkuqJKtqamUl6oSb@0bVZCoqUmqegA)

Instead of using `exit`, I instead set `$_` (implicit output) and `$\` (newline after output, including implicit output) to the null string if there's a match (and to `1` if there's no match). A `print` is still required because implicit output is only enabled if there's at least one byte of input (thus, we need to explicitly print something if we're given an empty string as input, which is distinct from the program).

Every A Pear Tree program needs to contain a checksum somewhere (that's the `MZpa` in this solution). Both my solution and the crack pick variable names (and vary other minor details of the code) in order to make the checksum consist entirely of ASCII letters.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175965/69850).

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5 `-p0777`, 10 bytes, score 10, safe

```
W)9r46<(k
```

The last character here is "shift out", character code 14 (decimal) / 0E (hex). All the others are printable ASCII.

Because we're using Perl's implicit I/O argument `-p0777`, the input is coming from standard input, and the output going to standard output.

### Solution

The program does the following:

> NUL-pads the input to at least 10 characters, then XORs with the string `svgOUT_TOP`

which means that the program itself, the only input producing the desired output, is:

> ```
> $_^=abc|$^
> ```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lPs42MSm5RiUOmf0vv6AkMz@v@L9ugYG5uTkA)

#### Explanation

> Perl has a number of special-purpose variables. For example, when using `-p0777` for implicit I/O, `$_` is input at the start of the program and output at the end of the program.
>
> Most of these variables have a very simple default value. However, the default value of `$^`, the currently selected top-of-page format, is the much longer string `STDOUT_TOP`. As such, we can use this as a very terse obfuscation method via XORing `$^` with the value we want to obfuscate (in this case, the program).
>
> In order to hide the telltale `_TOP` at the end, I padded the program itself out to 10 characters via adding in an `abc|`, meaning that all the characters of `STDOUT_TOP` would be XORed with something; the choice of `abc|` at the start was an easy way to keep the output mostly printable (and to make it harder to spot that I was XORing with a string made mostly of capital letters, because in ASCII, lowercase XOR uppercase is lowercase).

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 50 bytes [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196430/60483)

Input and output from/to stdin/-out. Output is different for each and every different input. Unique output when given the source code:

```
218216195196222130136136132192197195196130241204136209197216206130201131244155157154215136138204197216138201138195196138195196218223222130131247131131
```

(That’s 150 digits)

Good luck!

Comment: Whoops! I see now that this challenge is long over... Weird that it popped up in my timeline/feed. Curious to see if anyone responds to this...

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196430/60483)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 35 bytes, Score: 7

**Input:**
From `stdin`

**Output:**
`QÕ
Ƿe`

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 18 bytes, Score 18, safe

It's a shame that this challenge didn't get more attention, but that's the way it goes sometimes.  I was going to leave this unsafe, but decided to post the solution before I forgot about it.

This should be quite easy to crack.

**Input** from `stdin`

**Output**

```
$`*2aJPJ#74(o);89
```

**Edit:**  I should mention that this expects the source in it's shortened form ... and now I've noticed that there is a missing byte (unprintable) from the result that I broke when I posted.  Should copy out now.  The hex values are `24 60 2a 13 32 61 4a 50 4a 23 37 34 28 6f 29 3b 38 39`

The concept was to remove print the first character and then remove the inverse index from the character, eg [chars]-[0,len([chars])..2]

The code is

```
$r;#AoW\U-@</u.?;;
```

which maps onto the following cube

```
    $ r
    ; #
A o W \ U - @ <
/ u . ? ; ; . .
    . .
    . .
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=JHI7I0FvV1xVLUA8L3UuPzs7&input=JHI7I0FvV1xVLUA8L3UuPzs7&speed=20)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes, Score: 21, Safe

Both the program and output size are counted using Jelly codepage.

#### Input

First command-line argument.

#### Output

```
-§ḋẇ"*YdĖDƘ>Ẉed€Ç+æạɦ
```

---

#### Solution

```
ØJiⱮÄÆNPḃØ⁵ịØJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDK/MRxvXHW453OYX8HBH8@EZjxq3PtzdDRT/j1cWAA)

Comment: Because converting from/to Jelly codepage is hard, it would be useful to have a verifier (that takes a program, convert it from UTF8 to Jelly, feed it with itself, convert from Jelly to UTF8, and check if it's equal to the expected output)

Comment: @user202729  [this Jelly program, `v⁼`](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef//duKBvP///y3Cp@G4i@G6hyIqWWTElkTGmD7huohlZOKCrMOHK8Om4bqhyaY), will yield `1` if the input evaluated as Jelly code with an input of the input is equal to the input and will either yield `0` or error (if the input is an invalid Jelly code) if not.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript Firefox, <10 bytes, Score: 52, from function argument input, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175395)

```
ZnVuY3Rpb24gYnRvYSgpIHsKICAgIFtuYXRpdmUgY29kZV0KfQ==


btoa
```

`btoa(btoa)` encodes the following string:

```
function btoa() {
    [native code]
}
```

which gives:

```
"ZnVuY3Rpb24gYnRvYSgpIHsKICAgIFtuYXRpdmUgY29kZV0KfQ=="
```

<sub>just copied</sub>

Comment: First of all, after doing the obvious, this isn’t actual code? Second, you don’t specify where input comes from. I would post a crack but honestly I’m not sure if this submission is valid.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175395/58563)

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to include the crack post in this post -- people can just click the link to view the crack.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 26 bytes, Score: 52, Safe

The program is not a REPL, but a full script that accepts `stdin` and explicitly prints to `stdout`.

#### Input

Standard input.

#### Output

```
6fc42353c98217ef5a2908a3c63d090aa9a55b2558b61294e06a
```

No, it's not an encryption method.

---

#### Solution

```
echo]hfd]257x#.3&u:stdin''
                   stdin'' Take the whole input
               3&u:        Convert to codepoints
         257x#.     Convert base 257 to integer
     hfd]           "Hex from Decimal"
echo]               Print to stdout
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5Iz82Iy0l1sjUvEJZz1it1Kq4JCUzT10dnxwA)

Answer (score 1):

## GCC 61->61 bytes

```
70 4F 92 73 08 D4 03 E7 65 DC D6 89 B5 AD BA 90 
97 26 31 10 F6 FA 0A 30 8F 24 69 0A A7 8B 59 9E 
A2 42 D5 67 B8 12 3A 1E 9D 25 80 F9 6B 25 32 C2 
EE 46 3F 8D 7E 0C 73 0F F0 93 C6 68 50
```

Full program, take input from stdin and output to stdout

Comment: So, is there a space after last `50`?

Comment: @tsh It's a hex dump

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6, 43 bytes, Score: 15, from stdin

```
49671296789805
```

Comment: Just checking, since your previous answer didn't follow the rules on a unique output for your program as input, can you confirm that this submission does?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pepe](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 23 bytes, score: 23, [cracked by MickyT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/175366/transformers-in-disguise-robbers-thread/176552#176552)

**Input:**

standard

**Output:**

```
RDCbn@?K]<[G98765TSR^PO
```

Comment: [cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176552/31347)

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 6 bytes, Score: 6

**Input**

From `stdin`, using `?`

**Output**

```
5\x1c"\x1c"9
```

Mind you that those are escape sequences for unprintable bytes. Replace the escapes with the literal chars. [Raw text available here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/31RGSUbJ8v9/nWg7nVibaD2bWAA)

Good luck with this one! See y'all next week!

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6, 31 bytes, Score: 39, from stdin - Cracked

[**Cracked here**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175440/66624)

```
().1111111111112222235abcegijkmnorstvy
```

Crude solution. Might survive.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175440/9296) your solution and I suspect that your program doesn't follow the rule that different inputs should produce different outputs.