# Narcissistic Quine

Tags: code-golf, string, quine

Write a program/method that:

- Becomes a quine when the input matches the source code;
- Doesn't halt otherwise.

This is code-golf, so shortest solution wins. Avoid any standard loopholes.

Comment: @PostRockGarfHunter Strengthened the requirements. Now this challenge differs from a cat program.

Comment: This is why we sandbox.

Comment: Here's a similar question, hopefully the answers can provide inspiration for others!
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11370

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write the shortest self-identifying program (a quine variant)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11370/write-the-shortest-self-identifying-program-a-quine-variant)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
“Ṿ;⁾v`¹⁻³$¿”v`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO/dZP2rcV5ZwaOejxt2HNqsc2v@oYW5Zwn@8sgA)

A program taking a single string argument and either printing its source if the string matches its source, or looping indefinitely if not.

### Explanation

```
“          ”v` | Evaluate the following string as Jelly code, using the string itself as argument:
 Ṿ             | - Uneval (effectively wrap the string in “”
  ;⁾v`         | - Append v`
       ⁻³$¿    | - While not equal to the original program argument:
      ¹        |   - Call the identity function
```

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>67</s> <s>60</s> 56 bytes

```python
exec(a:='print(s:=input())\nwhile s!="exec(a:=%r)"%a:1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7UiNVkj0cpWvaAoM69Eo9jKNjOvoLREQ1MzJq88IzMnVaFY0VYJpkq1SFNJNdHKUF2TfJ0A)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
a='s=input();print s\nwhile s!="a=%r;exec a"%a:1';exec a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9FWvdg2M6@gtERD07qgKDOvRKE4Jq88IzMnVaFY0VYp0Va1yDq1IjVZIVFJNdHKUB3K@f@/SElJiVzdQK0A)

Comment: Is there anything in 3.8 that this answer relies on?

Comment: @Cruncher https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions

Answer (score 8):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 20 bytes

```
{`".~"+{.2$=}do\;}.~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/vzpBSa9OSbtaz0jFtjYlP8a6Vq8OhygA)

### Explanation

```
{                }.~ # Evaluate the following string as GolfScript code, using the string itself as argument:
 `                   # - Uneval (effectively wrap the string in ""
  ".~"+              # - Append .~
       {.2$=}do      # - Do While not equal to the original program argument:
                     #   - (Basically do nothing)
               \;    # - If this loop ends, discard the extra copy of the input
```

Comment: What is the relationship between Jelly and GS?

Comment: @RGS It's simply because Jelly is (indirectly) based on GS.

Comment: why did the GS port of a jelly answer get more votes than the answer it was porting?

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 20 bytes

```
"34çìD«Êi["34çìD«Êi[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fydjk8PLDa1wOrT7clRmNysMtCwA)

---

## Explanation

```
"34çìD«Êi["           - string literal
           34ç        - push the character "
              ì       - prepend to the string literal
               D«     - duplicate the string (producing the code)
                 Êi[  - loop if it's not the same as the input
                      - else implicitly output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 15 bytes

```
QWnjN B"QWnjN B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzA8L8tPwUkJSv//r6SkhCYGFPmXX1CSmZ9X/F83BQA)

### Explanation

```
QWnjN B"QWnjN B
Q                 implicit print input
      B"QWnjN B   evaluates to ["QWnjN B", "QWnjN B"]
   jN             join elements in list with '"' as separator (will be source code)
 Wn               keep looping while input does not equal source code
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 89 bytes

```php
eval($s='$a=chr(39);$b="eval(\$s=$a";$c="$a);";$b.$s.$c!=$argn?:die($b.$s.$c);for(;;);');
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkU8sSczRUim3VVRJtkzOKNIwtNa1VkmyVwOIxQAmVRCVrlWRbJZVETWsgK0lPpVhPJVkRKF6UnmdvlZKZqgET1LROyy/SsLbWtFbXtP5PO6P/5ReUZObnFf/XdQMA)

This is the best I have found so far, at the beginning it wasn't a port of @Mukundan's answer, but it pretty much ends like it. I will try to improve it later..

EDIT: saved a byte with `!=` instead of `==` so I can remove the `1`

EDIT2: saved 16 bytes using vars for repeated strings

Answer (score 2):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 17 bytes

```
«•.x=xe²xw³1#1:?
```

## Explanation

```
«•.x=xe²xw³1#1:?<SPACE> #
«                       # Push the following function to the stack and execute
 •.                     # Append a space (A non-function character) and stringify
   x=                   # Assign the stringified function to x
     xe                 # Is x equal to the top of the stack?
       ²                # "Double Function" to execute if true
        x               # Push x to the stack
         w              # Output
          ³             # "Tripple Function" to execute if false
           1            # Push a truthy value to the stack
            #1          # A function that just repeatedly pushes true
              :         # While the top of the stack is true. Thus, loop forever
               ?        # If a, than b, else c
                <SPACE> # Used to ensure the function qualifies as a quine.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6///Q6kcNi/QqbCtSD22qKD@02VDZ0Mpe4T8uCQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 36 bytes

```
f=s=>{x=`f=[f]`ifx==s x elsewhile1z}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678/z/NttjWrrrCNiHNNjotNiEzrcLWtlihQiE1pzi1PCMzJ9WwqvZ/QVFmXokGF2caEHMqEaNFiYtTk0vzPwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)*

```javascript
f=x=>eval(`while(x!='f='+f);x`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P822wtYutSwxRyOhPCMzJ1WjQtFWPc1WXTtN07oiQfN/QVFmXolGmoYSAYVKmpr/AQ)

Comment: [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P822wtauwtZWPc1WXTvNvsIqTUPzf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGEjY1Spqa/wE), though I'm not sure if exceeding the recursion limit counts as infinite. At the very least, you can get rid of the trailing semicolon

Comment: @JoKing Yeah I thought about that but I don't think that really counts, since it's bounded by the size of the stack, thanks for the -1, I did think about something similar with `f=x=>x=='f='+f?x:eval("for(;;);")` but it's 33 bytes

Comment: Another 33 `f=x=>eval(\`while(x!='f='+f);\`)||x`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 50 bytes

```perl
$_=q($_='$'."_=q($_);eval";<>eq$_?print:eval);eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rZQA0ioq6jrKUHYmtapZYk5StY2dqmFKvH2BUWZeSVWICGIBDl6AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <sup><s>29</s></sup> 21 bytes

```
OvA="Us@¶`OvA=`+Q+A}a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/37/M0VYptNjh0LYEEDNBO1DbsTbx/3917BLqAA)

### Explanation

```
OvA="Us@¶`OvA=`+Q+A}a
  A="Us@¶`OvA=`+Q+A}a // Set A to string literal
Ov                    // Evaluate A as japt code
       @              // Function
        ¶`OvA=`+Q+A   //   Check if input equals "OvA" + '"' + A (Q is '"')
                   }  // End Function
                    a // Call function repeatedly until it returns a truthy value
     Us               // Slice off first 0 chars of input
                      // Implicit Output
```