# Self-loathing program/function

Tags: code-golf

Simple task, write a program/function that returns error **if and only if** presented with itself.

The program must give a valid output for any input other than itself.

For the error part, you can only use errors already built in errors that comes with your language of choice. New/ self-defined error messages are not allowed.

The output should be of the same type as the input. (int, float, string, array, boolean, etc.) Except in the case if presented with itself of course.

Standard loopholes forbidden, lowest byte wins.

Comment: This seems to be, essentially the same as [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/198515/narcissistic-quine), with the only exception being erroring instead of halting.

Comment: But it is different since invoking an error is required

Comment: Please [avoid making assumptions about language features](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/43319). Not al languages have built-in errors, not all can take inputs of variably type, etc.

Comment: Related/possible dupes: [same challenge, but looping indefinitely if the input is anything other than itself](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/198515/52210) and [same challenge, outputting a truthy/falsey value depending on whether the input is equal to itself](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11370/52210).

Comment: If a language doesnt contain errors than this challenge is obviously impossible in those language why ru even trying

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
"34çìD«QiF"34çìD«QiF
```

Outputs the input if it's not equal to the program. If it is equal, it will output the error:

> ** (RuntimeError) Could not convert `"34çìD«QiF"34çìD«QiF` to integer.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fydjk8PLDa1wOrQ7MdEPh4JMDAA)

**Explanation:**

It's based on this base quine: [`"34çìD«"34çìD«`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fydjk8PLDa1wOrUaw/v8HAA).

```python
"34çìD«QiF"           # Push string "34çìD«QiF"
           34ç        # Push 34, converted to a character: '"'
              ì       # Prepend it to the string: '"34çìDJQiF'
               D«     # Append a copy of itself: '"34çìDJQiF"34çìDJQiF'
                 Qi   # If it's equal to the (implicit) input-string:
                   F  #  Start a loop, using the (implicit) input-string as argument,
                      #  resulting in the error
                      # (implicit else: use the implicit input as implicit output)
```