# Simple "hyena" program

Tags: code-golf, quine

Write a program that takes a string as an input. For the input:

- If the input **doesn't** match the source code, the program shall output the input intact. (Hence a cat)
- Otherwise, the program shall fall in an infinite loop. (So actually not a cat)

Comment: Can the program read its own source code?

Comment: @Sisyphus Since that is considered cheating in quines, no.

Comment: So a cross between a [narcissist program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11370/76162) and a truth machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write the shortest self-identifying program (a quine variant)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11370/write-the-shortest-self-identifying-program-a-quine-variant)

Comment: that looks very very similar

Comment: @pppery While similar, not completely identical.

Comment: I chose to slam this since in most languages it's basically just wrapping the target in a while loop and then adding a print after the loop. Adding extra code to a quine isn't always trivial, but I think most of the answers there are competitive here after a small change.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-0p`, <sup><s>38</s> <s>37</s></sup> 32 bytes

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to a comment by @Sisyphus on another answer.*

```ruby
eval s="1until$_!='eval s=%p'%s"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P7UsMUeh2FbJsDSvJDNHJV7RVh0qpFqgrlqs9P9/cGZuQU6qwqOGORmVqXmJjxrmKhQU5acXJeb@yy8oyczPK/6va1AAAA)

The `-0` flag sets the null byte as the input record separator. Without `-0`, a loop would also be entered if the input consisted of the code repeated on more than one line.